# What happens when a creature with a flight speed falls from great heights?

Tags: dnd-4e, flight

What happens if a creature with a flight speed/altitude of 4, suddenly, for whatever reason, finds itself 50 squares above ground?

1. Does it fall/crash until it reaches an altitude of 4, then fly as normal?
2. Does it crash all the way to the ground?
3. Is it able to keep moving, but unable to fly anywhere but down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flying creature creature with an altitude limit falls if it is above its altitude limit *at the end of its turn*.

From the Rules Compendium, p210, Flight Traits:

> **Altitude Limit:** If a creature has a specified altitude limit, the creature falls at the end of its turn if it is flying higher than that limit. For example, a creature that has an altitude limit of 2 falls at the end of its turn if it is flying higher than 2 squares.

When a flying creature falls, it follows special rules; from the Rules Compendium, p209, Falling:

> **Flying Creatures:** If a creature falls while it is flying, it descends the full distance of the fall but is likely to take less damage than a creature that can't fly. Multiply the creature's fly speed by 5 and subtract that distance from the fall, then figure out falling damage. If the difference is 0 or less, the creature lands without taking damage from the fall.

Essentially, flying creatures safely descend their flight speed, then fall the rest of the way.

So if a pixie (flight speed 6, altitude limit 1) ends its turn 10 squares up, it would safely descend 6 squares to 4 squares up, then fall the last 4 squares (taking 1d10 dmg & being knocked prone, barring a trained Acrobatics check).